# How can i change my font size when loading webview?

Tags: android, json, webview

How can I change my font size in android when I load string data using web view, I don't want it in my java program, want to change font size in my XML files, because it working for both small and tab devices.

```
viewHolder.web.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
viewHolder.webSettings =viewHolder.web.getSettings();
viewHolder.webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(14);

String pish = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Regular.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont;font-size: medium;color:#000000;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String description=faqArrayList.get(i).getDescription();
String myHtmlString = pish + description;
viewHolder.web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I used the code mentioned above in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

1. Add **`<bool name="isTablet">false</bool>`** to **values/dimens.xml**

   ```
   <resources>

       <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>

   </resources>
   ```
2. Add **`<bool name="isTablet">true</bool>`** to **values-sw600dp/dimens.xml**

   ```
   <resources>

       <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>

   </resources>
   ```
3. Add following code to your activity:

   ```
   if (context.getResources ().getBoolean (R.bool.isTablet)) {
       web.getSettings ().setTextZoom (120); //large font for tablet
   } else {
       web.getSettings ().setTextZoom (100); //default for phone
   }
   ```

Comment: i want to change it in my XML file > is it possible ??

Comment: Not in layout file. But you can change font using HTML content that you are loading. Please post content or HTML part so that I can guide you.

Comment: when i running on tab device its fonts size remain same that running on small device

Comment: Do you want to change font size for tab only?

Comment: both tab and mobile device

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if any help is required

Comment: This is exactly i want ,it working fine, Thanks @user12345